# How to get random data with specific no of records with different ids

Tags: mysql

I have a one table named questions which having column chapter_id foreign key of chapter table.Now i want random questions from question table with no of questions from different chapter.

ex: like i want 2 random questions from chapter 2, 4 random questions from chapter 3 , 5 random questions from chapter 4.

How is his possible with single mysql query.

I tried this but gives rows from first query only.

```
(select `id`,`chapter_id`,`question_name` from question q1 where chapter_id=7 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3)
    UNION ALL
    (select `id`,`chapter_id`,`question_name` from question q2 where chapter_id=6 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: select q.* from questions q join chapter c on q.chapter_id = c.id where c.id = 2 limit 2 UNION select q.* from questions q join chapter c on q.chapter_id = c.id where c.id = 3 limit 4 UNION  select q.* from questions q join chapter c on q.chapter_id = c.id where c.id = 4 limit 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select `id`,`chapter_id`,`question_name` from question q1 where chapter_id=7 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3
   UNION 
select `id`,`chapter_id`,`question_name` from question q2 where chapter_id=6 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2
```